# Run Powershell script in Azure Automation or ADF Custom Activity?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-automation

What could be the best way to automatize the following process in Azure:

1. Run PowerShell script
2. Store the output (.csv or .tsv) directly in ADLS (or in a StorageAccount and copy them to ADLS)
3. Move data from ADLS to one Azure SQL DB

For points 2 and 3 think that the best way is to implement them in ADF with copy activity and some U-SQL scripts.

For point 1 I don’t have a clear idea how to implement it. I’m considering a Custom Activity in ADF or implement it on Azure Automation.
Which method is more appropriate for this purpose?

Comment: You could get the code within the powershell script to open a connection to SQL Server (and probably ADLS) write the results directly there. In other words do 1 and 2 (and maybe even 3) all inside the powershell script.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid this was another option that I consired.
¿Any idea of what could be the better option to run the powershell script (ADF Custom Activity, Azure Automation or Azure Function)?

Comment: Azure Automation

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comment, you could use **Azure Automation runbook** to run the powershell script. There are two runbook types to run the powershell, for the advantages and limitations, see [PowerShell runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks) and [PowerShell Workflow runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-workflow-runbooks).

For more details to use them, see [My first PowerShell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell) and [My first PowerShell Workflow runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual).